# how to "pull down" a parameter when refactor in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

before refactor:

```
public interface Service {

    public void hello(Person p);
}

public class BlackPersonServiceImpl implements Service {

    @Override
    public void hello(Person p) {
        //...
    }

}


public class WhitePersonServiceImpl implements Service {

    @Override
    public void hello(Person p) {
        //...
    }

}

public class BeforeRefactor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = args[0];
        Person p = JSON.parseObject(str, Person.class);
        Service service = getServiceFromSpringContainer();
        service.hello(p);
    }

    private static Service getServiceFromSpringContainer() {
        //...
        return null;
    }
}
```

after refactor:

```
public interface Service {

    public void hello(String str);
}

public class WhitePersonServiceImpl implements Service {

    @Override
    public void hello(String str) {
        Person person = JSON.parseObject(str, Person.class);
        //do something to person...
        //...
    }

}

public class AfterRefactor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = args[0];
        Service service = getServiceFromSpringContainer();
        service.hello(str);
    }

    private static Service getServiceFromSpringContainer() {
        //...
        return null;
    }
}
```

That's what I want(I think "pull down" is not the "right" word to describe it...).

I tried "introduce parameter object" in eclipse, and it does not work.

There are many implementations of "Service". I dont want to change them one by one.

Is there a good way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it somewhat for a single class and a single method (although it's akward and a succession of small refactoring steps), but not across several types at the same time.